# WSLTTY/MINTTY Fails on Launch

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, mintty

After a machine restart last night my WSLTTY/MINTTY terminal crashes when I attempt to launch it. It displays an error message briefly before it crashes that reads:

`note: backend error output: Assertion failed: connectRet == 0 (nix-sock.c: nix_local_connect: 67)`

I'm on Windows 10, using WSL1, **not WSL 2**. I uninstalled WSLTTY and re-installed the most recent version, 3.5.1. The issue remained. I then uninstalled Ubuntu and re-installed the most recent version, 20.04.03 LTS. The issue still remains. I also tried installing an older version of WSLTTY/MINTTY (1.7.9) and received a slightly different error:

`/bin/wslbridge: Exit 1 wslbridge error: failed to start backend process note: backend error output: wslbridge=backend.cc:44: int{anonymous}:: connectsocket(int const string &): Assertion 'connectRet==0' failed`

So it seems the issue may have something to do with something called the wslbridge? Looks like there is an original version and a second version. wslbridge2.exe and wslbridge2-backend both live in wsltty/bin/ (with the newest version of WSLTTY/MINTTY).

I had WSLTTY/MINTTY configured pretty heavily and really enjoyed the way I had it set up. I'm really hoping I can get it working again and don't have to switch to a different terminal emulator or use the Windows one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.